# get the query string value wordpress

Tags: wordpress, url

I want to get the values from the url witch are in this format
localhost/appcara/blog/page/2/
I want the value 2 which is in the query string like ?page=2
I have tried this code

```
$paged = (get_query_var('page')) ? get_query_var('page') : 1;
```

but it is not useful .can any body help me ?

Answer (score 0):

Try using this code:

```
$pager_id = get_query_var('paged');
$postsPerPage = 5;

if($pager_id != 0) {
    $search_args = array( 'cat' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage, 'paged' => $pager_id);
} else {
    $search_args = array( 'cat' => 1, 'post_status' => 'publish', 'posts_per_page' => $postsPerPage);
}

$results = new WP_Query( $search_args );
```